# Sharing code between a UITableView and a UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview

My iPad and iPhone interfaces use a `UICollectionView` and a `UITableView` respectively.  In each case, there is a lot of commonality:

- each has the same number of sections (hard-coded)
- each section has the same number of respective rows/items (derived from the same data source)
- each has identical cell content (these are custom views built using auto layout so are suitable for both cases)
- each has identical section headers and footers (again, custom content)
- each can respond to certain notifications in the same way (e.g. when new data is received, refresh the data source) but with custom parts also (reload the `UITableView` vs reload the `UICollectionView`)
- each will present the same controllers via cell selection, though the `UITableView` will push the new controller and the `UICollectionView` will use a popover.

I am using a shared parent class to cater to some of this. This approach seems especially well suited to the data requirements - the parent class builds the data and is responsible for maintaining it. I use two subclasses to present the data - one with a UITableView and the other  UICollectionView.

The presentation side is a little less clean. To take the simplest example, when the table/collection view needs to know the number of sections, in each case I am relying on a customized method in the parent:

```
return [super sectionsCount]
```

This allows me to set many values only once and have both views updated.

Then comes the part that is working poorest. Again, to simplify, consider the header view for the first section. In both cases, this should be identical. I have a custom UIView subclass that I want to use, with a couple of properties that will be set the same. The problem here is that the re-usable header for a table view section expects a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and the counterpart for a collection view expects a `UICollectionReusableView`. So to accommodate this, I'm having to create subclasses of these simply to hold the header view I want in both.  So in summary:

What I want: UITableView and UICollectionView should use the same UIView subclass as the header for section. The custom properties of that view should be set identically in each case.

What I am having to do:

- Build the required UIView subclass for the header.
- Build a UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass that holds one such header. It's init does nothing more than add a header view.
- Build a UICollectionReusableView subclass that equally does nothing more than add a header view.
- When the collection view needs a header, create an instance of the UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass. Set its properties.
- When the table view needs a header, create an instance of the UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass. Set its properties.

Once I have to do this for footers, and especially cells, things are getting kinda icky. I have three times the classes I should need, and I'm repeating all of my code for setting custom properties of the view.

How can I best re-use this logic between the `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create stock `UICollectionReusableViews`, `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews`, etc. and add your custom view as a subview. If you need to access the custom view later, you can set its `tag` property and use `[view viewWithTag:]`.

Comment: Sure - I will take a significant performance hit though if I apply this theory to cells.

Comment: I will also still have to configure the view's  settings twice using identical code.

Comment: Why do you think you'll take a significant performance hit? And I don't see why you need to configure the view twice. Have one method or block of code that configures the view. Then add it to the appropriate container view.

Comment: For instance, if I return a stock UITableViewCell when dequeueing, and *then* add the child views to its contentView, I am doing this every time a cell is needed. I am not recycling the most costly parts of the cell (all of the subviews), only the outer shell.

Comment: Re. the view configuring. If I have a shared parent VC with child TV/CV controllers, which is the appropriate container view? Are you suggesting in both children I pass the vanilla view and the item up to the parent and say 'configure this view using this data'? That's the only way I can see to avoid duplicating the configuration code (which is mostly setting a bunch of labels, images, etc based on an objects properties - the duplication is because for both the TV and CV the object, the properties, and the view are basically the same).

Comment: "I am not recycling the most costly parts of the cell (all of the subviews), only the outer shell" But you can recycle the content as well as the cell. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you get a handle on the content view using [cell viewWithTag] and then you reconfigure it with the new data.

Comment: "Are you suggesting in both children I pass the vanilla view and the item up to the parent and say 'configure this view using this data'?" That is one way to do it, e.g. with a delegate or a callback block. But if you're using a custom view class, just define a `configureWithData:` method on your custom view.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about `configureWithData:` - I considered it but it seems like I'm mixing model and view. Maybe its ok. I'm still missing something on the cell maybe. Take a `UICollectionView`. Register a plain old `UICollectionViewCell` for cells. When asked for a cell, we will create or recycle one of these cells, and then add the custom view. Are you suggesting that after dequeueing, I first check if the viewWithTag is there already (meaning it was recycled)? And if so, re-use its existing subview instead of adding one?

Comment: "And if so, re-use its existing subview instead of adding one?" Yep, exactly. I agree `configureWithData` can mix model and data, depending on your data, but I like it as a practical solution. You can define multiple `configureWithData` type methods if you need more reusability.